# Avro schema for a given class

Tags: java, avro

What would be the equivalent avro schema for following class

```
class A {
  String s;
  List<String> l;
}
```

I have following, but its doesnt work:

```
{
 "name" : "A",
 "type": "record",
 "fields": [
   {
     "name": "s",
     "type": "string"
   },
   {
     "name": "l"
     "type": "array",
     "items": "string"
   }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add details when you say *it doesn't work*. What error message does your program output? What is the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `array` type needs to be nested in another dictionary like so:

```
{
 "name" : "A",
 "type": "record",
 "fields": [
   {
     "name": "s",
     "type": "string"
   },
   {
     "name": "l"
     "type": {
       "array",
       "items": "string"
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: This creates an `String[]`, not a `List<String>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Avro IDL to basically have the same thing

```
protocol SampleProtocol {
    record A {
        string s;
        array<string> l;
    } 
}
```

You can refer the Avro documentation on how to actually get a Java Arraylist class when generating the class, otherwise it's an array